# How do I launch a program inside a shell script and have the shell script continue, even though the program remains open

Tags: bash, shell

I am using bash on Ubuntu.  I would like to have a shell script open a program and continue on to the next line of the shell script, even though the program has not terminated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding an `&` to a command places it in background.

example:

```
/path/to/foo    
/path/to/bar     # not executed untill foo is done


/path/to/foo &    # in background
/path/to/bar &    # executes as soon as foo is started
```

Read more about job-control [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_77.html) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Basics)

Answer (score 4):

Use something like this `(my-long-running-process &)` . This will launch your script as a separate process in the background.

Answer (score 3):

You must run the process in the background, but you must enable job-control first. Otherwise, you cannot kill or bring the process to foreground if desired.

To enable job-control, execute:

```
set -m
```

To run some task in the background, execute:

```
task &
```

To manipulate the background task, use the *jobspec* syntax (`%[n]`). For example, to kill the last launched process, execute:

```
kill %
```

Note that enabling job-control is required only if you're actually running a *script* (as stated in the question). If running interactively, job-control is already enabled by default.

The manpage for `bash` has much more information in the **JOB CONTROL** section.

Comment: To me this one seems to be the best answer, "/path/to/foo &" by itself didn't work until I added "set -m" first (using bash 5.2).

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657602

It looks like all you have to do is add a & at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that `&` puts the command in background, but still look here, it may be because your terminal does not print its prompt again, after the script execution. Or more exactly, because it prints its prompt again but the app you launched outputs something after in the terminal.
For example, this script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
firefox --new-instance -P Something &
```

or this one, as suggested by @alecov

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -m
firefox --new-instance -P Something &
```

will give this in gnome-terminal (Ubuntu 23.10):

```
laurent@laurent-GL73-8SD:~/redacted$ ./fire.sh 
laurent@laurent-GL73-8SD:~/redacted$ Gtk-Message: 22:35:26.454: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

(firefox:47696): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:35:26.571: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/3289/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 22:35:26.571: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(firefox:47696): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:35:26.573: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/3289/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 22:35:26.573: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

If you want a clean prompt, you need to type enter again.